# input to Websphere Message Broker

Tags: websphere, integration, force.com, messagebroker

I have an requirement to send data from Oracle DB to SFDC account.

Scenario:
Oracle DB -> WebSphere Message Broker(MB) -> WebSphere Message queue(MQ) -> DataPower (Service) -> SFDC account

I’m not sure how the data will be pushed to MB? Do MB has the capability to pull the data from any source?

If it doesn’t have that capability, what can be done to move the data from Oracle DB to WebSphere Message Broker(MB)? What's the communication protocol generally used? How to integrate Oracle DB to WebSphere Message Broker(MB)?

Comment: Show some effort. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the DataBaseInput Node.

More information here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc34041_.htm

There is a sample for this node in the samples gallery you can use to familiarise yourself with the node.